# kendo ui grid sortable editable will lose edit if cells in other rows are clicked, using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, grid

I am using kendo grid and angularjs to make a table, I wanted the rows be reorderable by drag-and-drop and the cells (particularly the first column) be editable. It all worked out except if I click cells in another row after editing a cell, the change is lost. I can press the tab key or the enter key to make the changes but if I click it will fail. Here is the example:
[CodePen example](https://codepen.io/lijian007/pen/JpLgBv)

```
    angular.module("KendoDemos", ["kendo.directives"])
    .controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $compile) {
        console.log("controller running.")

        $scope.data = [{ id: "1", label: undefined, files: "file a" },{ id: "8", label: "", files: "file z" }, { id: "3", label: "item c", files: "file c" }, { id: "2", label: undefined, files: "file b" }];
        $scope.mainGridOptions = {
            dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                autoSync: true,
                data: $scope.data,
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "id"
                    }
                }
            }),
            columns: [{
                    field: "label",
                    title: "Label",

                    width: "150px"
                },
                {
                    field: "id",
                    title: "ID",
                    editable: false,
                    width: "100px"

                },
                {
                    field: "files",
                    title: "Files",
                    editable: false
                }
            ],

            editable: true

        };

        $scope.sortableOptions = {
            filter: ".k-grid tr[data-uid]:not(.k-grid-edit-row)",
            hint: $.noop,
            cursor: "move",
            placeholder: function(element) {
                return element
                    .clone()
                    .removeAttr("uid")
                    .addClass("k-state-hover")
                    .css("opacity", 0.65);
            },
            container: ".k-grid tbody",

            change: function(e) {


                var grid = $scope.ssgridcrda;
                var dataItem = grid.dataSource.getByUid(e.item.data("uid"));
                console.log("sorting ", dataItem);
                grid.dataSource.remove(dataItem);
                grid.dataSource.insert(e.newIndex, dataItem);
            }
        };


    })
```

Comment: The issue purely is with your angular code especially in the way how the change is captured (two way binding). Have a look at this [PEN](https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/ddemeN) where I have replicated the same scenario without using AngularJS and it is working fine.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However, the rows in your table cannot be reordered by drag-and-drop, while my code allows that. That was one of the the goal. Also AngularJS is required.

Comment: Please note the rows in the table can be reordered by drag-and-drop. This is a desired feature.

Comment: You may include the `sortableOptions` section back in the code which I had removed.

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work. Also I am looking for the angularJS solution.